# A phrase describing someone who is lazy

Tags: phrases, expressions, pejorative-language

Is there a phrase that would describe a person that is lazy beyond anything reasonable?

Comment: Bone idle (sometimes born idle)

Answer (score 2):

Possibile expressions are:

[Indolent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indolent):

> - Disinclined to exert oneself; habitually lazy.

[Couch potato](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/couch+potato):

> - a lazy person whose recreation consists chiefly of watching television and videos

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Haha! - I love "cuochi potato". It sounds like something you would get in a Japanese restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

Bone Idle or Bone Lazy:  Mynamite suggested bone idle in a comment, above.  His comment deserves to be promoted to an answer.  Bone Idle from Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary  "Origin -- Early 19th century: expressing idle through to the bone...... See also bone lazy."    (Edit corrected typos and made clearer that Mynamite was the first with this term.)

Comment: Thanks ab2... btw I've deliberately remained gender-neutral on this site, always interested to see people's assumptions...... :)

Answer (score 1):

***Slothful***

*Sloth* is [one of Christianity's Seven Deadly Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth_%28deadly_sin%29) and one of [Buddhism's Five Hinderances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances). *Sloth* therefore has implications of *vice* or *sin* or *excess* that merely *lazy* does not.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sloth): habitual disinclination to exertion; indolence; laziness

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say "feckless," except that to my mind, that word implies not only laziness, but a dose of helpless incompetence to go along with it. I agree with the alternative "Indolent."

Answer (score -2):

**[good-for-nothing](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=good%20for%20nothing%20definition)**

> a lazy, feckless person.
>
> synonyms: ne'er-do-well, layabout, do-nothing, idler, loafer, slob,
>   lounger, sluggard, laggard, slugabed, malingerer, shirker; ...
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=good%20for%20nothing%20definition)

**Other possibilities**

> lazybones
>
> slouch
>
> slug
>
> do-nothing
>
> bum
>
> lotus-eater
>
> slugabed
>
> wastrel
>
> good-for-nothing
>
> good-for-naught
>
> goof-off
>
> drone
>
> loafer
>
> slacker

Comment: Again with a list with no definitions and no links!! Does good-for-nothing mean lazy?

Comment: @Josh61 - Ah, sorry.  I've edited to give the definition of my main answer. I think it would be impractical to give definitions for all of them.

Comment: Ah, chasly, did you happen to leave any words for the rest of us?

Comment: At least he's not lazy, or a sluggard, or a lazybones, or, ....

Comment: Long lists of synonyms are discouraged on EL&U and with good reason too.